# Ошибка при запуске vncserver

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, desktop, display, vnc

Что значат ети ошибки, и как их исправить?

Заранее спасибо.

```
$ vncserver -localhost no -geometry 800x600 -depth 24
```

Вывод:

```
New Xtigervnc server '*******.internal:1 (u0_a300)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /home/u0_a300/.vnc/passwd *******.internal:1 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/u0_a300/.vnc/*****.internal:5901.log ===================
===============================================================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/u0_a300/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
        tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 3151... success!
```

```
$ tail ****.internal:5901.log
```

Вывод:

```
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x556b137ff400 for event 2
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x556b137ff400 for event 3
3NI3X0 New Xtigervnc server '******.internal:1 (u0_a300)' on port 5901 for display :1.
3NI3X0 Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /home/u0_a300/.vnc/passwd ******.internal:1 to connect to the VNC server.
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
vncconfig: unable to open display ":1"

** (process:3156): WARNING **: 10:41:41.958: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Мой файл `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

env:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/u0_a300
LOGNAME=u0_a300
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/home/u0_a300
LANG=C.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=u0_a300
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
_=/usr/bin/env
```